# field not update after click dropdown angular 2

Tags: forms, angular

I have a project with Angular 2.

I have a formbuilder with field who use Google Places API. Everything works except my field with dropdown after click on element.

The new value is set in the field but value of formbuilder is not.

[image]

**My function formbuilder :**

```
createFormStep1() {
    this.rideForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        departure: [this.rideModel.departure, [Validators.required]]
        // ...
    });
}
```

**My template :**

```
<aside class="section-form">
        <div class="form-group">

            {{ rideForm.value.departure }}
            <input type="text" #autocomplete (focusout)="onKeyOrigin($event)" class="form-control" formControlName="departure" placeholder="Ville, adresse, métro, gare...">
            <app-control-messages [control]="rideForm.controls.departure"></app-control-messages>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Comment: I assume you do have a `form`-tag with `[formgroup]="rideForm"`?

Comment: Exactly `<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(rideForm.value, rideForm.valid)" [formGroup]="rideForm">`

Comment: Okay, good, this kind of information could be shown in question, so that people know this without needing to ask :) Could you try to add `[(ngModel)]="ridemodel.departure"` to your input field. Have no idea if it actually makes any difference, but try :)

Comment: I have already tried but no change :( Thx for your help