# Google place directive not updating form control value in angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, google-places-api, angular2-directives

I have a google place directive; when I type on my input field it suggests places and upon selection it outputs the place name. I see the selected value in input field, but my form control value shows only what I typed in the input field. I am using model driven form. For example: if I type **bha** and then select **Bharat Diamond House**, the input field shows correctly **Bharat Diamond House** but the form value gets only **bha**. My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598895/change-an-inputs-ngmodel-value-using-a-directive-angular-2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739968/field-not-update-after-click-dropdown-angular-2)

My directive looks like this:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/forms';
import {Address} from './model/google_place';

declare var google:any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[googleplace]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(input)' : 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class GoogleplaceDirective  {
  @Output() setAddress: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() adr_address: EventEmitter<any>  = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() place_id: EventEmitter<any>  = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() formatted_address: EventEmitter<any>  = new EventEmitter();

  modelValue:any;
  autocomplete:any;
  private _el:HTMLElement;
  place:Address;

  constructor(el: ElementRef, private model:NgModel) {
    this._el = el.nativeElement;
    this.modelValue = this.model;
    var input = this._el;
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', ()=> {

      (<HTMLInputElement>input).value=(<HTMLInputElement>input).value.split(',')[0];

      this.place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (this.place && this.place.place_id){
        this.invokeEvent();
      }
    });
  }

  //invokeEvent(place:Object) {
  invokeEvent() {
    this.setAddress.emit(this.place);
    this.adr_address.emit(this.place.adr_address ? this.place.adr_address : null);
    this.formatted_address.emit(this.place.formatted_address ? (this.place.formatted_address) : null);
  }

  onInputChange() {

  }
}
```

**[PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/FWOUq0O06b2LQLjvtm4S?p=preview)**

Comment: What the code should do onInputChange?

Comment: It's not doing anything now, I've kept it for future use if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Google places, but I can tell you that much that the changes are not affected, because you need to use `patchValue` here, and patch the value you get from the directive.

***HOW*** you do this, you would need to figure out, probably need to add EventEmitter from your directive, that returns your value, which you can then patch something like the following:

```ts
this.createEventForm.patchValue({venue_name: theValue})
```

And as I have noticed from questions before, there seems to be change detection issues with google map/places, so you'll probably need to use [**`ChangeDetectorRef`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html)

```ts
import { ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(public createEventFb:FormBuilder, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

and when you need to detect the changes:

```ts
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

This I noticed when I tested your plunker and it was needed. Here is your [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nezIA120VCed1UteD8Hk?p=preview), where I did a ***EXTREMELY POOR*** solution. But I wanted to test it, and here I manually assign the value you get from your directive in the `venue_name` (only), to showcase the `patchValue` on that field.

Comment: I already figured it out, I used setValue. Forgot to post the solution, posting now. But, thanks anyway for looking into it.

Comment: Yeah, setValue and patchValue are almost the same, with some minor differences, but both will work :) But yes, no problem! Have great day and happy coding :)

Comment: In Angular 5+ `patchValue` is not working for me until you focus and then blur any input of the form. The only working solution is triggering the change detection manually as indicated in this answer.